# Activate popup menu after timed mouseover and then de-aactivate on mouse out

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a menu that will appear when you hover over an element for a set period of time. If you were to hover over this element but then mouseout before the set time, the menu will not appear. The idea is to prevent the user from accidentally activating the menu when they are simply moving their mouse across the element quickly.

By default the menu is set to `display:none;` in my CSS. Then when they successfully hover long enough, I add a class of `.active` to it to set the display to `block.`

My problem is that once the mouse is over the element long enough (in my test case I've set it to 1 second), mousing over to the newly displayed menu counts as a mouseout and I lose the menu. I had assumed since the menu is a child of the element I'm listening to that it would still count as mousing over that element. I was wrong I guess!

[Amazon.com's main menu](https://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn) is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div id="drop-nav-trigger">
  Menu

  <div class="drop-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is my javascript. I've got some jQuery jumbled in there for changing the class of my menu.

```
var timeoutId = null;
var el = document.getElementById("drop-nav-trigger");

/* Activate menu after a delay. */
el.addEventListener('mouseover',function() { 
                   timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function(){

  $(".drop-nav").addClass("active");

  }, 1000);
} );

// Cancel action if mouse moved out within 2 sec
 el.addEventListener('mouseout',function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  $(".drop-nav").removeClass("active");
});
```

And here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/EVYbWx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tirck is to use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout` <kbd>[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/9bt168zn/)</kbd>

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/